# EmberJS no model was found but it's there

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, ember.js, model

I'm writing an ember-cli app. I have the following model:

```
// app/models/school.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: '' })
});
```

It was generated using an ember generator like all my other models. It has a functioning unit test as well that tests for the default value of it's name attribute. All tests are green until another model belongs to school like this:

```
// app/models/professor.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: '' }),
  email: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: '' }),

  courses: DS.hasMany('course'),
  posts: DS.hasMany('post'),
  school: DS.belongsTo('school')
});
```

This test is totally green until I add the school attribute. It's even green with `'model:school'` defined in the `needs` array of the `moduleForModel` helper:

```
// tests/unit/models/professor-test.js
// this is green w/o belongsTo('school') in the model
moduleForModel('professor', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  needs: ['model:school', 'model:post', 'model:course']
});
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: No model was found for 'school'
```

Here's the models directory

```
$ ls app/models/
course.js  post.js  professor.js  school.js  student.js
```

Why is it not finding my model?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope. I stopped using Ember. Didn't really like it much.

Answer (score -2):

You need to *import* the *school* model in your test:

```
import '[appName]/models/school';
```

Comment: But I haven't had to do that for any other test. It's an ember-cli app.